# Session management with spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, httpsession

I have to implement session management with spring security.

1. I want HttpSession to get started **on successful login only**
2. How to add logged in users details into session

*But in my code, the session gets created on loading login page itself..*

My **SecurityConfig** class is here:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("akashm").password("akash123").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("girishp").password("girish123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/homePage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/myProfile").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/viewUsers").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("pswd")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid")
            .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login?invalid");
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() { //enabling the concurrent session-control support
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

- Reference links are acceptable

Comment: Most likely your session is opend in your JSP page. AFAIK that's the default behavoir of JSP. You have to disable it.

Comment: @dur How to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an `ApplicationListener` with event `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` to populate session with user details required.

```java
@Component
public class LoginListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired 
    HttpSession httpSession;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event)
    {
        //Do whatever with httpSession object
    }
}
```

> I want HttpSession to get started on successful login only

HttpSession can be `@Autowired` as both are spring beans.

> But in my code, the session gets created on loading login page itself..

Session is created by spring security as soon as the login page is accessed for the first time but the session created at that time is not authorized and after successful  login by the user a new session will be created for that user and previous session will be destroyed.

Comment: You didn't answer OP's question. How should a `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent`prevent a HTTP session? And how should autowiring help? In both cases the HTTP session is already there. And the last part is completly wrong. Spring doesn't create a session if the login page is accessed.

Comment: @saad Surya Thank you so much. I added ur suggested listener as it is and simply added a sysout in `onApplicationEvent` method. but no event gets listened in my case. What would be the problem? pls help

Comment: @Akash Mulik make sure to add `@Component` annotation on class and that the class is scannable by spring as a bean.

Comment: Not a valid answer.